# solving refresh of page after wrong login for right login

Tags: jsp

I have made a login page in *jsp* in which my `index.jsp` page redirects after getting username and password to `login.jsp` and if I put the right password and username it goes to `success.jsp` but if I put wrong username or password then it goes to `error.jsp` now there only page `index.jsp` is again include but when I put there the right username and password it is not redirecting to `login.jsp` where it validates and forward page to `success.jsp` now please tell me how to resolve this problem I m new in project making so please tell me in detail.

Comment: It's really hard to understand the question from this several lines of unformatted text.

Comment: How exactly you are doing the `redireect`. Can you show some code?

Comment: thanx Digvijay for ur concern my problem is over now